# javascript double JSON call on the loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitch

Friends,

Currently I'm implementing twitch.tv app using json as my part of my freecodecamp course. Using twitch api, I have to call json twice, to get user and stream data. I also do this in the loop, as I have multiple streamers I want to follow. Here you can see my [code](https://codepen.io/BurtMacklin/pen/YVdRmL).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var streamerList = ["MisterRogers","freecodecamp"]; 
getStream(streamerList);
});

function getStream(streamerList) { 
for (var k = 0; k < streamerList.length; k++) {
 var userURL = makeURL("users", streamerList[k]);
 var streamURL = makeURL("streams", streamerList[k]);
  $.getJSON(userURL, function(data) {
    var displayName = data.display_name;
    var logo = data.logo;
    $.getJSON(streamURL, function(data){
      var status, game;
      console.log(data);
      if (data.stream === null){
        status = 'Offline';
        game = 'No Content Available';
      } else if (data.stream === undefined){
        status = 'Not available'
        game = 'Channel Closed';
      } else {
        status = 'Online';
        game = data.stream.game;
      }
      addRow(displayName, logo, status, game);
    });
  });
}
}
```

In the example I use two streamers (freecodecamp and Mister Rogers), one of them is online, and the other offline. However, the data at the second json call is being messed up and in my app I see them both as offline. Its working fine if I remove freecodecamp or Mister Rogers and leave only one streamer. But two or more are not working. I'm quite new to js, so if you could explain the gaps in my logic, I would be very grateful. Cheers.

Comment: Might be a collision with the naming of your parameters.  I believe the inner function call's `data` is hiding the outer `data` variable.  Try renaming one of them and see if your result changes.

Comment: Noup, renaming one of `data` variables doesn't solve the issue. Anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by myself with some examples I found on internet. The problem with this code was that in the `$(document).ready(function(){})` I pass string array `streamerList` as an argument for `getStream()` function, however, the `streamerList` variable is not seen within the second call of JSON (look at the code above). Because that call is in the function of first JSON call. Due to this reason, `streamURL` in the second call becomes `undefined`. To solve this issue I had to make variable `streamerList` global and run `foreach` loop. Here is my working solution:

```
var streamerList = ["MisterRogers", "freecodecamp"];

function getStream() {
    streamerList.forEach(function(channel) {
        function makeURL(type, streamer) {
            return (
            "https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/" +
            type +
            "/" +
            streamer +
            "?callback=?"
            );
        }
    $.getJSON(makeURL("streams", channel), function(data) {
        var status, game;
        if (data.stream === null) {
            status = "Offline";
            game = "No Content Available";
        } else if (data.stream === undefined) {
            status = "Not available";
            game = "Channel Closed";
        } else {
            status = "Online";
            game = data.stream.game;
        }
        console.log(status, game);
        $.getJSON(makeURL("users", channel), function(result) {
            var displayName = result.display_name;
            var logo = result.logo;
            addRow(displayName, logo, status, game);
        });
    });
});
}
function addRow(displayName, logo, status, game) {
    var divRow = document.createElement("div");
    divRow.className = "row";
    divRow.innerHTML =
        '<div class="col-md-4"></div>\
         <div class="col-md-1"><img src="' +
        logo +
        '"/></div>\
         <div class="col-md-3"><blockquote>\<p>\
         <a href="http://www.twitch.tv/' +
        displayName +
        '" target="_blank">' +
        displayName +
        '</a></p>\
         <footer><cite title="Source Title">' +
        status +
        ": " +
        game +
        '</cite></footer></blockquote></div>\
         <div class="col-md-1></div>';
    document.getElementById("content").appendChild(divRow);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    getStream();
});
```